How to change top line color of ModalBottomSheet in Jetpack Compose?
I write code of ModalBottomSheet, and I want to remove top line and make sheet transparent. Is it possible?
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ModalBottomPopup(
    showSheet: Boolean,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    sheetState: SheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        skipPartiallyExpanded = true,
    ),
    shape: Shape = BottomSheetDefaults.ExpandedShape,
    containerColor: Color = Color.Transparent,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(containerColor),
    tonalElevation: Dp = BottomSheetDefaults.Elevation,
    scrimColor: Color = Color.Transparent,
    dragHandle: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = WindowInsets.displayCutout,
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit,
) {
    if (showSheet) {
        ModalBottomSheet(
            onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
            modifier = modifier,
            sheetState = sheetState,
            shape = shape,
            containerColor = containerColor,
            contentColor = contentColor,
            tonalElevation = tonalElevation,
            scrimColor = scrimColor,
            dragHandle = dragHandle,
            windowInsets = windowInsets,
        ) {
            content()
        }
    }
}


I make container, content color to transparent, but it's not help

If you want to remove the drag handle you can use this:
ModalBottomSheet(
    // ...
    dragHandle = null,
) {
    content()
}


I hide drag handle like this:
dragHandle: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle(color = Color.Transparent) },

